# How Do I Create a Valid S3 Presigned POST Request?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signature, pre-signed-url

I want to create a pre-signed POST request to upload a file to S3 that I can pass out to clients. As far as I know, I'm following the AWS documentation to do this. Below is my request to create a pre-signed POST request:

```js
import { createPresignedPost } from "@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post";
import {getS3} from "./aws-clients";
    
    
const Bucket = 'my-bucket';
const Key = 'my-key';
    
    
(async () => {
    const s3 = getS3();
    const {url, fields} = await createPresignedPost(s3, {
        Bucket,
        Key,
    });

    console.log(`url: ${url}, fields: ${JSON.stringify(fields, null, 2)}`);
})();
```

And here is the output from that request:

```json
{
  "url": "https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/",
  "fields": {
    "bucket": "my-bucket",
    "X-Amz-Algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
    "X-Amz-Credential": "AKIA4V7ALGPKSB2AEP4E/20230515/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request",
    "X-Amz-Date": "20230515T032603Z",
    "key": "my-key",
    "Policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0xNVQwNDoyNjowM1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJteS1idWNrZXQifSx7IlgtQW16LUFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IlgtQW16LUNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiJBS0lBNFY3QUxHUEtTQjJBRVA0RS8yMDIzMDUxNS91cy1lYXN0LTEvczMvYXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0In0seyJYLUFtei1EYXRlIjoiMjAyMzA1MTVUMDMyNjAzWiJ9LHsia2V5IjoibXkta2V5In1dfQ==",
    "X-Amz-Signature": "594df7cd680b04c99dcf48a105e15c6d1f8109d1c6b61be98420b03d20979a40"
  }
}
```

I'm using those values to create the following client request form:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Copy the 'url' value returned by createPresignedPost() -->
    <form action="https://my-bucket.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Copy the 'fields' key:values returned by S3Client.generate_presigned_post() -->
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="my-key" />
        <input type="hidden" name="AWSAccessKeyId" value="AKIA4V7ALGPKSB2AEP4E" />
        <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMy0wNS0xNVQwNDoyNjowM1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJteS1idWNrZXQifSx7IlgtQW16LUFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IlgtQW16LUNyZWRlbnRpYWwiOiJBS0lBNFY3QUxHUEtTQjJBRVA0RS8yMDIzMDUxNS91cy1lYXN0LTEvczMvYXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0In0seyJYLUFtei1EYXRlIjoiMjAyMzA1MTVUMDMyNjAzWiJ9LHsia2V5IjoibXkta2V5In1dfQ==" />
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="594df7cd680b04c99dcf48a105e15c6d1f8109d1c6b61be98420b03d20979a40" />
        <input type="file" name="file" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form, I get the following error:

> SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not
> match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing

What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use s3 pre-signed urls instead?

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer my question, but I'll go down the rabbit hole. The client chooses the file to upload, so how would I do that given that I don't know what they are going to select ahead of time? I'm willing to do anything that works.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a presigned URL without knowing what file (for example, a specific JPG file) will be uploaded?

Comment: Yes. And it looks like I'm finally getting some traction with the s3-presigned-post approach. Lot's of confusing docs and incorrect code out there (or I'm just unlucky or looking in the wrong places). I did find the section of AWS docs that talks about using an HTML form with a pre-signed URL (which I was unaware of when I started). However, I found their documentation confusing. So, not stuck yet. I'll update this when I know more.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73664043

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the HTML form approach for now. I wanted to post a POC written in node that should be easy to modify to get it working as client/server. During my investigation I encountered lots of incorrect code and very lousy, misleading documentation. I'd like to think that this POC is helpful to others that may be involved in a similar search. So below is a working POC:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {createPresignedPost, PresignedPost} from "@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post";
import {readFile} from 'fs/promises';
import {defaultProvider} from "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node";
import {S3Client} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import {AwsCredentialIdentityProvider} from "@aws-sdk/types";

/*
    this is server-side code
    an endpoint will be provided for the client to call to get the data it
      needs to upload a file directly to S3
 */
async function getPresignedPostData(Bucket: string, filepath: string, 
                             mimeType: string): Promise<PresignedPost> {

    const s3 = getS3({
        signatureVersion: 'v4',
    });

    return await createPresignedPost(s3, {
        Bucket,
        Key: bucketKey(filepath),
        Fields: {
            'content-type': mimeType
        }
    });
}

/*
    this is client-side code
    this is currently running on node as a POC
    there may be some minor differences to be made to get this to run in a 
      browser
        (perhaps the Buffer & Blob handling for instance)
    also it may make more sense to do this in an HTML form instead of 
      javascript
 */
async function uploadFile(bucketName: string, 
              filepath: string, mimeType: string) {
    try {
        const {url, fields} = 
          await getPresignedPostData(bucketName, filepath, mimeType);

        const formData = Object.entries(fields).reduce((data, [key, value]) => {
            data.append(key, value);
            return data;
        }, new FormData());

        const buf = await readFile(filepath);

        formData.append('file', new Blob([buf]));

        return await axios.post(url, formData)

    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`file (${filepath}) upload failed: ${e}`);
    }
}


// support stuff //////////////////
function bucketKey(fullPath: string): string {
    let idx: number;
    idx = fullPath.lastIndexOf('/');
    if (idx === -1)
        idx = fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\');
    if (idx === -1)
        return fullPath;
    return fullPath.substring(idx + 1);
}

type ResourceOptions = {
    region: string
    credentials: AwsCredentialIdentityProvider
}

function getResource<T>(factory: (options: ResourceOptions) => T, 
                                  additionalOptions?: object): T {
    const defaultOpts = {
        region: process.env.AWS_REGION as string,
        credentials: defaultProvider()
    }
    additionalOptions = additionalOptions || {};
    const allOpts = {...defaultOpts, ...additionalOptions};
    return factory(allOpts);
}

const getS3: (additionalOptions?: object) => S3Client = (additionalOptions) =>
    getResource(options => new S3Client(options), additionalOptions);


// test it
(async () => {
    const ret =
        await uploadFile('some-bucket', 'path-to-some-JPEG-image', 'image/jpeg');

    console.log(ret.data);
})();
```